# Can a node.js wait for callbacks in an ejs file to complete before sending to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What methodology can be used to get similar functionality to classic ASP or PHP in the non working code below (it doesn't work because the response HTML doesn't include the data from the database callback)?

**App.js:**

```
HTML_port = 8080;
HTML_path = '/html';
sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
db = new sqlite3.Database('databases/equipment.db');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + HTML_path)); 
app.engine('.ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + HTML_path);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('*.ejs', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + HTML_path + req.url, function(err, result) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); }
    res.end(result);
  });
});
app.listen(HTML_port);
```

**index.ejs**

```
<html>
   <body><%
     db.all("SELECT id,function FROM mydatabase", function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (rows.length != 0) { 
          rows.forEach(function (row) {
            %><div><%=row['id']%>">-<%=row['function']%</div><%
          });
        }
     });
  %></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yea you are right, U need to put the render function in callback to make it work.

In order to do that, put the

```
db.all("SELECT id,function FROM mydatabase", function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render("*",{rows:rows})
});
```

in to a JS file.
And modify the templates like this

```
<html>
   <body>
      <% if (rows.length != 0) { 
          rows.forEach(function (row) {
            %><div><%=row['id']%>">-<%=row['function']%</div><%
          });
        }
      %>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a methodology to keep the database query in the .ejs file (similar to PHP)?

Comment: @shaun5 Don't do that. A kitten dies every time you include a database query in a view in Node.js.

Comment: @shaun5 It is not recommended. I never do that before so I have no idea. Since nodejs is about no blocking, implementing db query in views definitely blocks the view which will slow your load time.

Comment: Whether the query is before or during render is really a moot point.  The page would still be 'blocked' until the query callback is executed.

Comment: @shaun5 yea you are right, this is not a good example for that. But for the question you asked. I think this is the way to go.